# Access dict key and return None if doesn't exist

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python what is the most efficient way to do this:

```
my_var = some_var['my_key'] | None
```

ie. assign `some_var['my_key']` to `my_var` if `some_var` contains `'my_key'`, otherwise make `my_var` be `None`.

Comment: What do you mean by "if it exists"?  May the name `some_var` be undefined in some cases?

Comment: I just edited it - to clarify - i'm trying to check for the existence of a key in a dictionary essentially

Comment: `my_var = some_var.get('my_key')`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Python will throw a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary so you can't write your code in quite the same way as your JavaScript.  However, if you are operating specifically with dicts as in your example, there is a very nice function `mydict.get('key', default)` which attempts to get the key from the dictionary and returns the default value if the key doesn't exist.

If you just want to default to be `None` you don't need to explicitly pass the second argument.

Depending on what your dict contains and how often you expect to access unset keys, you may also be interested in using the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the `collections` package. This takes a factory and uses it to return new values from the `__missing__` magic method whenever you access a key that hasn't otherwise been explicitly set. It's particularly useful if your dict is expected to contain only one type.

```
from collections import defaultdict

foo = defaultdict(list)
bar = foo["unset"]
# bar is now a new empty list
```

N.B. the docs (for 2.7.13) claim that if you don't pass an argument to `defaultdict` it'll return `None` for unset keys. When I tried it (on 2.7.10, it's just what I happened to have installed), that didn't work and I received a `KeyError`. YMMV. Alternatively, you can just use a lambda: `defaultdict(lambda: None)`

Comment: **KeyError** is what's thrown when you access a key that doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Answer (score 72):

You are looking for the [`get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of `dict`.

```
my_var = some_var.get('some_key')
```

The `get()` method will return the value associated with `'some_key'`, if such a value exists. If the key is not present, then `None` will be returned.

Answer (score 18):

The great thing about the `.get()` method is you can actually define a value to return in case the key doesn't exist.

```
my_dict = { 1: 'one', 2: 'two' }
print my_dict.get(3, 'Undefined key')
```

would print.

```
Undefined key
```

This is very helpful not only for debugging purposes, but also when parsing json (in my experience, at least), and you should prefer using `get()` over `[]` as much as possible.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming `some_var` is a dictionary, you need [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
my_var = some_var.get('my_key')
```

This result defaults to `None` if `my_key` is missing, but you can supply a different default:

```
my_var = some_var.get('my_key', default)
```

Answer (score 10):

In python `"|"` is translated to `"or"`, so:

```
my_var = some_var or None
```

Edit:

You've edited your initial post. The correct way to do what you want is:

```
my_var = some_var.get('my_key', None)
```

Comment: None is useless, default is None --> http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Comment: It's just an example to illustrate the use of dict.get.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    my_var = some_var
except:
    my_var = None
```

But honestly this probably doesn't get to the heart of what you're trying to do...  We need more context to more fully answer.

Comment: I just added a clarification - some_var is actually a dictionary and i want to ensure the key exists in it otherwise use None

Answer (score 0):

For a **new** dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# None is the default, but you can change this default value
d = defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

For an **existing** dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# convert a dictionary to a defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: None,d)
```